# mysql - loop through all rows and update all objects in json array

Tags: mysql, json, loops

For mysql 5.7, I have a table `copy_jobs` with a column of json type `job_configs`.

`job_configs` has a property `configurations` which is an array of objects.

Example of data in `job_configs`:

```js
{"configurations": [
    {
        "role": "Introduction", "role_id": 1, "employee_id": 1, 
        "first_payment": "15.63", "second_payment": "46.88", 
        "employee_number": "00001", "employee_last_name": "Mendes", 
        "first_payment_made": false, "employee_first_name": "Mario", 
        "second_payment_made": false, "total_bonus_percentage": 25
    }, {
        "role": "P & D", "role_id": 2, "employee_id": 2, 
        "first_payment": "12.50", "second_payment": "37.50", 
        "employee_number": "00002", "employee_last_name": "Parker", 
        "first_payment_made": false, "employee_first_name": "Shaun", 
        "second_payment_made": false, "total_bonus_percentage": 20
    }
]}
```

I need to run a migration that will add the properties `"fumbled": false` and `fumblesCaught: []` to each object in the `configurations` array of every row for this table.

I thought that

```
UPDATE copy_jobs 
SET job_configs = JSON_SET(job_configs, '$.configurations[*].fumbled', false);
```

would work at least to add `"fumbled": false`, but this returns the error message: `In this situation, path expressions may not contain the * and ** tokens.`

Is there a way to run a single command in which it will add both new properties to every object in the `configurations` array?

Or would I need to create a procedure I could then call, that would get all rows and for each row loop through the `configurations` object and one by one add the two new properties to the objects?

EDIT:

After the comment from @wchiquito I created a procedure thinking this would work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateRoleConfig()
BEGIN
DECLARE counter Int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE totalRows Int;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO totalRows FROM copy_jobs;
SET totalRows = totalRows + 1;

WHILE counter < totalRows DO
    SET @offset = counter;
    PREPARE getRowSql FROM 'SELECT job_configs INTO @jsonConfigs FROM copy_jobs LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?';
    EXECUTE getRowSql USING @offset;
    SELECT concat('selected row is ', @jsonConfigs);

    UPDATE copy_jobs SET job_configs = JSON_SET(job_configs, '$.configurations', CAST(
        REPLACE(
            JSON_EXTRACT(@jsonConfigs, '$.configurations'),
            '}',
            ', "fumbled": false, "fumblesCaught": []}') AS JSON
        )
    );
    SET counter = counter + 1;
END WHILE;
END
```

However this results in overwriting all of the rows `configurations` arrays with a single object, resulting in the same for all rows.

The output of `@jsonConfigs` is also strangely always the value of the object overwriting all others, which is coincidentally the value of the `configurations` array found in the first row of the table.

```js
{"configurations": [
    {
        "role": "Introduction", "role_id": 1, "employee_id": 1, 
        "first_payment": "15.63", "second_payment": "46.88", 
        "employee_number": "00001", "employee_last_name": "Mendes", 
        "first_payment_made": false, "employee_first_name": "Mario", 
        "second_payment_made": false, "total_bonus_percentage": 25}
    ]
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try a rudimentary idea [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f51c758733243fb5eba138b9acaed6df).

Comment: @wchiquito I have updated my question after looking at your fiddle. Still having issues

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work by also storing the ID in a variable and then updating and fetching the json with that ID.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE updateRoleConfig()
BEGIN
DECLARE counter Int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE totalRows Int;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM copy_jobs INTO totalRows;
SET totalRows = totalRows + 1;
SET counter = 0;

WHILE counter < totalRows DO
    SET @offset = counter;

    SELECT concat('offset is ', @offset);
    SELECT concat('counter is ', counter);

    PREPARE getIdSql FROM 'SELECT id FROM copy_jobs LIMIT 1 OFFSET ? INTO @rowId';
    EXECUTE getIdSql USING @offset;
    PREPARE getJsonSql FROM 'SELECT job_configs FROM copy_jobs WHERE id=? INTO @jsonConfigs';
    EXECUTE getJsonSql USING @rowId;

    SELECT concat('selected row is ', @jsonConfigs);
    SELECT concat('selected row id ', @rowId);

    SET @json = JSON_SET(@jsonConfigs, '$.configurations', CAST(
        REPLACE(
            JSON_EXTRACT(@jsonConfigs, '$.configurations'),
            '}',
            ', "fumbled": false, "fumblesCaught": []}') AS JSON
        )
    );

    UPDATE copy_jobs SET job_configs = @json WHERE id = @rowId;
    SET counter = counter + 1;
END WHILE;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Do you really need the stored procedure?, try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d76a3305eb1504a56bfa0ca7a8803d34).

Comment: @wchiquito I actually didn't try that! So glad you took the time to show me that it works in a single query. Thanks. You should post it as an answer so I can upvote it!